# Sharepoint 2010 Event Receiver Item Deleting and Updating

Tags: sharepoint-2010

While deleting an item I want to update another list.
Below is my code.

```
 public override void ItemDeleting(SPItemEventProperties properties)
        {
            base.ItemDeleting(properties);

            string listName = properties.ListTitle;

            if (listName == "Training Instances")
            {
                using (SPSite site = new SPSite(properties.WebUrl))
                {
                    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                    {
                        string title = properties.ListItem["Title"].ToString();

                        SPList trainingSubscriptionsList = web.Lists.TryGetList("Training Subscriptions");

                        SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
                        query.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Training' /><Value Type='Text'>" + title + "</Value></Eq></Where>";

                        SPListItemCollection listItemCollection = trainingSubscriptionsList.GetItems(query);

                        foreach (SPItem ts in listItemCollection)
                        {
                            if (ts["Status"].ToString() == "Available")
                            {
                                ts["Status"] = "Pending";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The problem is the item get deleted but the update is not happening.
Any help is very much apperciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to update the item:

```
...
    foreach (SPItem ts in listItemCollection)
    {
      if (ts["Status"].ToString() == "Available")
      {
        ts["Status"] = "Pending";
        ts.Update(); // or SystemUpdate()
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've always had the best luck doing validation in the "ing" events and updates in the "ed" events. Try using ItemDeleted instead.

Comment: Hi Rob, I've tried using the ItemDeleted event but in this event all the object (ListItem) and properties is null. http://www.sharepointalex.co.uk/index.php/2010/06/beforepropertiesafterproperties-in-event-receivers-i-always-forget-this/ . So I can't get the title of the item that I'm about to delete.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also new to sharepoint, does not understand what's the problem.

Call this method after performing your work, may be it works
base.ItemDeleting(properties);